# C++ partial template specialization & multiple symbol definitions error

Tags: c++, templates

I've been trying to analyze this problem in several ways now, but I can't figure out.

My use case is - I have a template class, and I want to provide a specific implementation for a specific type, while keeping the generic implementation for the rest.

Here's the code:

```
template< typename T >
struct SomeClass
{
    void foo();
};

template< typename T >
void SomeClass< T >::foo()
{
    printf( "generic impl." );
}

template<>
void SomeClass< char >::foo()
{
    printf( "char-specific impl." );
}
```

And everything works fine, as long as the entire code is located in the CPP file next to the code that's using it.

As soon as I move the code to dedicated files, like so:

**SomeClass.h**

```
#ifdef _SOME_CLASS_H

template< typename T >
struct SomeClass
{
    void foo();
};

template< typename T >
void SomeClass< T >::foo()
{
    printf( "generic impl." );
}

#endif
```

**SomeClass.cpp**

```
#include "SomeClass.h"

template<>
void SomeClass< char >::foo()
{
    printf( "char-specific impl." );
}
```

I get a linker error saying that void SomeClass< char >::foo() has already been implemented.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to declare a member function of a specialized template class you need to first define the specialized class:

```
template <>
struct SomeClass<char>
{
  void foo ();
};
```

Only then can you also define the actual function implementation:

```
template <>
void SomeClass<char>::foo () { /* do something */ }
```

Comment: That's not true, you can specialize members without defining entire specialized class.

Comment: @Rost, how do you mean, can you post an example of it?

Comment: @mauve C++ allows to specialize separate members of template without specializing entire template. OP can just add specialized function member forward declaration to header and it will work as expected. See my answer for syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Add a forward declaration of specialized function member into header:

```
template<> void SomeClass<char>::foo();
```